# How to select element in html which is without any "div" in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I want to style the text selected in chrome tools in below screenshot, how can I do that?

The text doesn't fall under any div to select, that confuses me.

More precisely the text in given screenshot has no div: "The elements of the C language library are also included as a subset of the C++ Standard library. These cover many aspects, from general utility functions and macros to input/output functions and dynamic memory management functions:"

[image: Text without any "div"]

Update 1: Screenshot is from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/. Class "C_doc" will affect whole div including h1 and others. I just want to affect the plain text.

Update 2: It will be hard for CSS alone, may be javascript can bring some magic to select that node and manipulate it's class.

Comment: @Paulie_D Requesting Javascript interference for manipulating textnode and then styling with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The text falls under the **div** which has the class **C_doc**.

Comment: But whole class "C_doc" will be affected. I  want to style the text in class "C_doc".

Comment: Textnode can't be styled standalone. To add the css for them they need a wrapper on top. So you have two options - Wrap the text you are targetting under a span tag and style this tag or Apply style to the class C_doc with the styles and override the style of other elements like h1, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but may be javascript can do some magic in manipulating the textnode. As mentioned earlier screenshot is from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ and I have not coded this up.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of html will not use .
Especially html that has been crafted be hand or generated by tools that are not targetting modern web pages.

You have to refer to the enclosing element (dic class=C_doc") in the specific example case).
And take care for treating any enclosed elements that should get different styling.

Answer (score 0):

The text is under the `<div class="C_doc">` so if you want to style the text just add your CSS styling to the class but remember it may affect your H1, H3 and other div tag inside the div.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you wrap the content with a P tag? Anyway the current content belongs to the DIV which has a class of "C_doc". You can add style to this class. You can avoid these changes to be reflected to your H tags by adding nested styes.

```
.C_doc { color:red;}
.C_doc h1 { color:black}
```

Comment: Screenshot is from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/. I don't want everything in "C_doc" class to be affected, just the plain text.